# Unable to resolve module, react native app

Tags: react-native, module, package.json

So i was starting to code a react native app and until this part was working fine:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';

import abacatezinImg from '..assets/abacatezin.png'

export function LoginScreen(){
    return(
        <View>
  
            <Text>
                Faça seu login para começar
            </Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

But then after adding `<Image source={abacatezinImg} />` between View and Text i got this error: undefined Unable to resolve module ..assets/abacatezin.png
I already tried somethings like modifying the package json with some solutions i found but didnt work.

My packae json file:

```
{
  "name": "timer_vovojuju",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~47.0.9",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.9"
    
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.14",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.70.6",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: This also appears in the error, idk if will help: None of these files exist:
  * abacatezin.png
  * ..\..\..\..\..assets\abacatezin.png\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error might be because of your image path import. Try importing like this `import abacatezinImg from '../assets/abacatezin.png'`

Comment: Yeah thats it haha thank you i didnt even noticed it was missing a /